# If $\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}=0$ on a connected open set, is $F$ constant?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let
$$F:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$$
be a smooth map, i.e. $F\in C^\infty(U)$. It is easy to prove that if $U$ is convex and
$$\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}=0\tag{1}$$
everywhere on $U$ and for all $i,j$, then $F$ is constant on $U$.

But what if $U$ is only *connected*, but not necessarily convex? Do we have a smooth map $F$ such that $(1)$ holds, yet $F$ is not constant?

Comment: If there is a piecewise $C^1$ path from $x$ to $y$ in $U$, then a line integral calculation very similar to the one you did in the convex case shows that $F(x)=F(y)$. Can you show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ will still be a constant map. Indeed, $U$ being a connected *open* subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is path connected ([here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected) is a proof). Let $x_0,x_1\in U$ be arbitrary. There is a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to U$ such that $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\gamma(1)=x_1$. Now, $I$ is compact and $\gamma$ is continuous, so $\gamma(I)$ can be covered by finitely many open balls $B\subseteq U$ (which are convex). Then, by what you know about convex open sets, we easily get that $F(x_0)=F(x_1)$.

**More Generally:** One can prove that if $F:M\to N$ is any smooth map between differentiable manifolds (such as spheres, tori, etc.) and $M$ is connected, then $F$ is constant if and only if its differential $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$ is the zero map for each $p\in M$ (which is exactly your equation $(1)$ in case $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ are open).

Answer (score 1):

Any function on a connected topological space $X$ that is locally constant on $X$ is globally constant on $X.$* The open convex result mentioned above gives the locally constant property in this problem, and the connectedness of $U$ finishes it.

*The proof is a typical "the good set is nonempty and clopen, therefore it's everything" argument.